# Solve Differential Equation, Homogenous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

[image]

Solve this Differential Equation. I am not sure the form, when I attempted to solve it I tried to solve it as Homogenous. But couldn't get it into a good form. This is a past quiz problem, not homework. If someone could tell me how to do this it would be awesome.

Comment: Hint: check for exactness

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y}{x}\ln\frac{x}{y}dx=(\ln \frac{x}{y}-5\frac{y}{x})dy$$
we know that $\ln\frac{a}{b}=-\ln\frac{b}{a}$, so the D.E will be
$$-\frac{y}{x}\ln\frac{y}{x}dx=(-\ln \frac{y}{x}-5\frac{y}{x})dy$$

then let$$u=\frac{y}{x}$$

Comment: What would you say the next steps from there would be

Comment: Says the guy who claimed in is post  that he had "tried...homogeneous."  Whatever you did when you "tried homogeneous", do to E.H.E.'s modification.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different approach, keep an eye out for useful patterns.

Note $y(ln(x/y))dx=(xln(x/y)-5y)dy$ can be rearranged to 
$$ ln(x/y)(ydx-xdy)=-5ydy$$

The term $(ydx-xdy)$ should look familiar, recall $d(x/y)=(ydx-xdy)/y^2$, or $(ydx-xdy)=y^2d(x/y)$.

That should allow you to simplify the equation.